# Weka disable Undo option

Tags: weka

Is there a way we can disable undo option in weka, by modifying some configuration file or through GUI?

My dataset is quite large, weka finishes processing fast however it takes a lot of time to save the undo information which is totally unnecessary for me, I found a link http://weka.wikispaces.com/weka_gui_explorer_Explorer.props where they have written that there is an undo option, however I am not sure how would it translate to the application level.

Comment: Please direct this question to the Weka mailing list. That is where the Weka experts are, and you will likely get the best answer within a few days there. They are really responsive and helpful there!

Comment: thanks, ill post a question on the mailing list.

Comment: Any resolution to this issue?

Comment: I would suggest to use Weka programmatically with java. It is way more fast and its easy to impelement. You can start here : http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code